# Show all googlesheets when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently working on project where I have two sheets "Sheet 1" & "Sheet 2". i have developed two html button named "Sheet 1" & Sheet 2. When user clicks "Sheet 1"-> it hides Sheet 2. Similarly, if the user clicks "Sheet 2"-> it hides Sheet 1. Currently button is working as per the below working if user clicks Sheet 1 and "it hides sheet 2" and when when user wants to click on "sheet 2" button, sheet 2 is already hidden and doesn't show.

```
function userclicked(userInfo){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var ws2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
ws2.hideSheet();
ws.getRange(1,1).setValue(userInfo.Text);
ws.showSheet();
}
function userclicked(userInfo1){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var ws2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
ws2.showSheet();
ws2.getRange(1,1).setValue(userInfo1.Text);
ws.hideSheet();
}
```

How do I show sheet "Sheet2" when Sheet2 button is clicked after clicking sheet1 button that hides "Sheet 2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The main issue is that you have 2 functions with the same name.
- Your general logic is correct, but to make your steps more clear you could check first if a sheet is hidden, and then unhide it:

  ```
   if (ws.isSheetHidden()) {
       ws.showSheet();  
   }
  ```
- The last suggestion is optional. You can omit the `if` statements and use only `ws.showSheet()` but it should be before `ws2.hideSheet()`, since you must have at least one sheet open in the `UI`.

### Solution:

Don't forget to modify the buttons to attach them the new function names:

```
function userclickedSheet1(userInfo){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var ws2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  
if (ws.isSheetHidden()) {
ws.showSheet();  
}  
ws2.hideSheet();
ws.getRange(1,1).setValue(userInfo.Text);
}


function userclickedSheet2(userInfo1){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var ws2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

if (ws2.isSheetHidden()) {
   ws2.showSheet();  
}   
ws.hideSheet();  
ws2.getRange(1,1).setValue(userInfo1.Text);
}
```

Comment: I would also separate out the Spreadsheet and Sheets as globals `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
const ws2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');` as they're common to both functions.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo thanks, that is a very good point. I am afraid there is a chance tha the OP has a lot more code which might uses `ws` or `ss` ? Of course, I assume it will be the same, but generally I am not a big fan of global variables.

Comment: Global vars in general in GAS aren't great practice, but have their uses in very restricted situations like this. I am also not sure if the conditionals are necessary here? As long as the `showSheet()` calls should always be before the `hideSheet()` calls there should be no issue: `ws.showSheet(); ws2.hideSheet(); ws.getRange().setValue();` and vice versa.

Comment: They are not, but I liked this structure better. It is optional though. This is why I said `to make your steps more clear you could` to show that this is an optional step.

Comment: I edited the script having the showSheet() before hideSheet and it worked. Thanks for the advice.